# Spring boot REST - Swagger Docs using Spring FOX and generate client SDK in same build

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, springfox

I am using java spring boot framework to create REST api for my project and I am using "springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui" for generating swagger documentation. I am able to see my documentation using the url http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.

How can I generate swagger.json / spec.json to a file without launching web url? I am planning to create client classes also in same build using this json.

Comment: You would need to create an integration test that produces the `swagger.json` and then consume the `swagger.json` in a step that generates your client library